# How do I mount a large NTFS volume with Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have a legacy application and third party software that both require NTFS volumes to operate. Changing the software would be a last resort.

The requirement is to have a central storage location for media (videos, images, etc) that each computer in a domain can access. The size requirement can be as high at 20 Terabytes.

My proposed solution is to create a domain and one of these computers to act as a simple file server with multiple volumes mounted and accessible from the other computers through DFS (Distributed File System). The reason why DFS is in the picture is we are looking to expand the DFS service to provide redundancy.

Is my proposed solution viable? I am willing to accept that I should be evaluating other storage/hosting solutions other than Azure that will allow me to meet the requirement.

Comment: UPDATE: I will accept the answer from @BrentDaCodeMonkey since it was the plan for us anyway :)

Comment: UPDATE2: Microsoft has since released a new service that would have given me a solution at the time. The feature is called "Azure Files" [http://blogs.technet.com/b/uspartner_ts2team/archive/2014/06/09/setting-up-a-file-share-for-the-new-azure-file-service.aspx]. It is backed by Blob Storage so most concepts should be familiar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet might be Windows Azure Virtual machines. In this model, an extra large virtual machine can mount 16 separate 1tb data drives. You'd have to combine multiple virtual machines to reach your 20tb requirements.

Comment: I currently have VMs set up and 2 VHDs ready to mount exactly as you suggest but it seems like a hack even at this "proof of concept" stage.

Comment: The current 1tb limit is because the data drives are persisted to Windows Azure Blob Storage. The page blobs there are limited to 1tb in size. But its that back end storage that gives you high availability in the local datacenter and geo-graphic redundancy out of the box with no additional setup necessary on your part.  And if you were able to change the legacy/3rd party software to directly leverage Windows Azure Blob storage, you'd find you have a maximum capacity of 100tb per storage account.

Comment: Don't forget that VHDs don't have anywhere near the performance characteristics as a local drive does.  If you're not leveraging the cloud storage service as it's designed and are only relying on VHDs then hosting your own service is still a reasonable option.

For one of my apps that does file storage I got around this but abstracting a service on top of the storage cloud and got rid of the need for VHDs altogether, that may not work for you however.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a reasonable solution.

1. Using Windows Azure Drives will give you NTFS.
2. Azure Drives are stored as virtual harddisks (VHD) in Blob Storage. I believe 1 drive can max contain 1 TB of data (a Blob store limitation), so you will have to mount multiple drives.
3. [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2011/04/16/using-smb-to-share-a-windows-azure-drive-among-multiple-role-instances.aspx) is an interesting article on sharing drives across multiple Role instances via SMB. Admittedly, I have not tried this myself.